# How to make a button show another button onclick?

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I'm trying to code a text adventure and since I've mostly been coding in PHP instead of Javascript, I think I forgot everything about Javascript :P

Anyway, I'm looking for how to show a new button after clicking another button. I have text in "innerHTML" so I don't know how to show another button using that. This is the code I have so far (and the new button is supposed to lead to "b" when you click it)

```
<script>
function one()
{
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML="You feel something on the ground, and you think it's a stick.";
}

function two()
{
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML="You pick up the stick. It might be useful for something.";
}
</script>

<div style="margin-left:15px; width:200px; margin-top:100px;">
<button onclick="one()">Feel around the cave</button>
</div>

<div style="margin-left:255px; width:200px; margin-top:-15px;">
</div>

<div id="entire" style="margin-left:490px; margin-top:-22px; width:400px; height:600px;"><div id="b"></div><div id="a"></div></div>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use the innerHTML to add another button? - Like `innerHTML += '<button onclick="nextFunction()">Text</button>'`? Have you tried this?

Comment: @ManiacalMonkey If I try that it doesn't work, it just deletes the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your one() function:

```
var newButton = '<button onclick="two()">Pick up stick</button>';
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML="You feel something on the ground, and you think it's a stick."+newButton;
```

This will put the button inside the "a" div.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your page add the following code in a script tag

```
var a = document.getElementById('a');
a.addEventListener('click', function () { two()});
```

You should look jQuery